# Got Rep bombed - sad face

Tags: support, moderators

[image]

It could be organic, but it looks like a good old fashioned rep bomb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The script that is supposed to handle those cases should catch it and roll it back in a day or two. If it doesn't, let us know.